# iOS: How to set programmatic alpha mask of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am able to set the alpha mask of my own custom object in the .sks file of the project, but I'm not sure how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: Just figured it out.

```
let presetTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "YOURIMAGE.png")
presetObject = SKSpriteNode(texture: presetTexture)
presetObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: presetTexture, size: presetTexture.size())
```

Comment: Just be careful with this, if your texture has a gap, the body will only make the left side of the texture

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is there any way to make it the whole texture and not just the left side?